# How Rails Makes Setters for each Model's associated columns, and how it does it for each data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- Where in rails source code does rails define *how* it dynamically creates setters for each model's associated column?
- Where in rails source code does rails define *how* it defines the setters for the different data types (ex: `Date`, `Integer`, `String`)?

I'm new to digging into source code so take it easy on me.  I have already dug around in the rails source code and I couldn't find the answers to these questions.

I thought the place to look was within [active_model/attribute_methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb).  It does not appear to be in there, or if it was I didn't quite grasp it, so a bit more explanation would help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done inside ActiveRecord: [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb)